# Create User count function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, count

I got this view for the table below:

```
SELECT count(Incident.ID_Incident) 
    FROM Incident WHERE Incident.End_User = 7
        AND Incident.Date BETWEEN '2018-12-01 07:54:44' AND '2018-12-18 00:00:00';
GO
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Incident(
ID_Incident INT         IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
Date        DATETIME                    NULL,
End_User    INT                         NOT NULL,
```

Here are some of the table values:

```
('2018-12-06 12:33:05', 003),
('2018-12-13 14:32:12', 010),
('2018-12-06 01:26:03', 015),
('2018-12-04 05:38:50', 012),
('2018-12-10 19:13:08', 011),
('2018-12-12 13:28:39', 005),
('2018-12-05 11:57:29', 006),
('2018-12-17 15:28:31', 007),
('2018-12-07 01:39:22', 007),
('2018-12-12 17:01:47', 009),
('2018-12-03 09:54:26', 010);
```

I need to turn that view into a Function. I dont know why it is not working.

Any advise would be great.

I wrote this:"

```
CREATE FUNCTION Total_case (@ID_End_User INT)
    RETURNS INT AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ID_End_User_Search     INT

            SELECT @ID_End_User_Search = COUNT(ID_Incident)
                FROM Incident i
                    WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User_Search 
                        AND i.Date BETWEEN '2018-12-13 14:32:12' AND '2018-12-18 00:00:00'
                RETURN (@ID_End_User_Search)
            END

GO


DECLARE @SearchValue INT;

EXEC @SearchValue = [dbo].Total_case 
    @ID_End_User = 7;
SELECT @SearchValue AS 'Total case per user.'
GO
```

Edit: Changed tags and added tables

Comment: Not working isn't very descriptive, elaborate please. Please also tag the DBMS you're using SMSS is just a client, though commonly used with SQL Server. The table's structure and sample data might also help.

Comment: Edit done. I'm still getting the main idea on how to post correctly

Comment: SSMS is just a client application, it has nothing to do with how you write a SQL query

Comment: Can you show in what way this is not working; a wrong result, an error (message) for example? Also look [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for advice on how to post an SQL question

Comment: First, why turn the view into a function instead of selecting from it with a `WHERE` clause? This won't affect performance. If you have a valid reason, eg you want to simplify a complex query, just use that `SELECT .. FROM thatView Where ...` in the functions body. Use `RETURNS TABLE RETURN SELECT ...` to convert it into an inline function

Comment: I would suggest using an inline table valued function here instead of a scalar function. It would be more flexible and performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you used the variable which you created in function in WHERE clause for filter. It is already empty and because of that you receive 0 result. Change `WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User_Search` to `WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User` then you will see the results. 
Also is this because of sample you used static date range in the function? If no, this is not efficient function, you need to modify your function every time when you need to change the date range.

This is corrected function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION Total_case (@ID_End_User INT)
    RETURNS INT AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ID_End_User_Search     INT

            SELECT @ID_End_User_Search = COUNT(ID_Incident)
                FROM Incident i
                    WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User
                        AND i.Date BETWEEN '2018-12-13 14:32:12' AND '2018-12-18 00:00:00'
                RETURN (@ID_End_User_Search)
            END

GO
```

This is better way to create function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION Total_case (@ID_End_User INT, @DateFrom DATETIME, @DateTo DATETIME)
    RETURNS INT AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ID_End_User_Search     INT

            SELECT @ID_End_User_Search = COUNT(ID_Incident)
                FROM Incident i
                    WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User 
                        AND i.Date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
                RETURN (@ID_End_User_Search)
            END

GO
```

Select for one user only:

```
SELECT DBO.Total_case(7,'2018-12-01 14:32:12' ,'2018-12-19 00:00:00')
```

Select for all users:

```
SELECT *, DBO.Total_case(END_USER,'2018-12-01 14:32:12' ,'2018-12-19 00:00:00') TotalIncidents
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT End_User 
        FROM Incident ) I
```

Comment: well done, you spotted WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User

Answer (score 0):

There is one error in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User_Search
```

It should be:

```
WHERE i.End_User = @ID_End_User
```